# Php phalcon join query doesn't return anything

Tags: php, phalcon

I am trying to run a query in phalcon php

```
$c_inv = ClientInvoices::query()->columns(['supplier_invoice_number', ' client_payment_req_id',
            'net_amount','markup_value','markup_type','net_qty'])
              // ->innerjoin("Invoices\Model\ClientPaymentRequests", "Invoices\Model\ClientInvoices.client_payment_req_id=CPR.id", "CPR")
             ->innerJoin("Contract\Model\ContractAdditionalInfoModel", "CAI.contract_id=Invoices\Model\ClientInvoices.contract_id", "CAI")
               // ->innerjoin("Contract\Model\Contract", "Contract\Model\ContractAdditionalInfoModel.buyer_contract_id=CO.id", "CO")
            ->where("Invoices\Model\ClientInvoices.client_payment_req_id=$id")->andWhere('Invoices\Model\ClientInvoices.status=3')->execute()->toArray();
```

When I do

```
print_r($c_inv)  or var_dump($c_inv)
```

Nothing shows on screen ,same query works on phpmyadmin ,how to figure out what's wrong with the query ?. Help me out please

Comment: a blank screen is a an indicator that errors / exceptions were thrown. enable the error display. ```ini_set('display_errors', 1);``` ```error_reporting(E_ALL);```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `->execute()->toArray()` with `->getQuery()->getSql()` and run the SQL code in PhpMyAdmin to see if it works.